# create a qrcode using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, qr-code

I was trying to create a QRcode generating app in python with tkinter that you enter color and then text and it generates a QRcode but it closes instantly upon startup. (the problem did not happen when I didn't have the color part), (in the future I'm also planning to add a save QR as png button)
here's what I have:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyqrcode
from tkinter import colorchooser
import re

def choose_color():
    x = 0
    # variable to store hexadecimal code of color
    color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title ="Choose color")
    print(color_code)
    x = 1
 
root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text = "Select color",
                   command = choose_color)
button.pack()

if 'x' == 1:
    str = 'color_code' # Your Hex

    match = re.search(r'^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$', str)

    if match:                      
        print('Hex is valid')
        ws = Tk()
        ws.title("PythonGuides")
        ws.config(bg='color_code')

        def generate_QR():
            if len(user_input.get())!=0 :
                global qr,img
                qr = pyqrcode.create(user_input.get())
                img = BitmapImage(data = qr.xbm(scale=8))
            else:
                messagebox.showwarning('warning', 'All Fields are Required!')
            try:
                display_code()
            except:
                pass

        def display_code():
            img_lbl.config(image = img)
            output.config(text="QR code of " + user_input.get())


        lbl = Label(
            ws,
            text="Enter message or URL",
            bg='color_code'
            )
        lbl.pack()

        user_input = StringVar()
        entry = Entry(
            ws,
            textvariable = user_input
            )
        entry.pack(padx=10)


        button = Button(
            ws,
            text = "generate_QR",
            width=15,
            command = generate_QR
            )
        button.pack(pady=10)

        img_lbl = Label(
            ws,
            bg='color_code')
        img_lbl.pack()
        output = Label(
            ws,
            text="",
            bg='color_code'
            )
        output.pack()
        
        ws.mainloop()

    else:
        print('Hex is not valid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the program closes immediately is because there is no `root.mainloop()`. Even if there was, there are a lot of other errors that would prevent the program from working.
The first problem is `if 'x' == 1`. Here you are comparing the literal string "x" to the number 1. These are never going to be equal, so the other window will never show up. I can see what you are trying to do with `x`, but it won't work as you expect. It is better just to get rid of `x` completely and call a function after the user selects a colour. I've called this function `show_qr_window`.
The second problem is how you get the hex code. You use the output of `colorchooser.askcolor`, which is a tuple containing an rgb tuple representing the colour and it's hex value. You only want the hex value, so you want `color_code[1]`, as the hex value is the second item. I've also added an `if` statement to make sure `color_code` is not None. `color_code` will be None if the user does not choose a colour and just closes the window. If the user has chosen a colour, it is passed to `show_qr_window`. Because we've checked the user has chosen a colour, you can get rid of all of the other validation as `colorchooser` will always return a valid hex value. You also no longer have to import `re`.
The third issue is that you've used `Tk` twice. This will cause your program to not work properly. Instead, change `ws = Tk()` to `ws = Toplevel()`.
The next issue is `str = 'color_code'`. This is not how you define a variable. You want to do `color_code = 'a string'`. In this case, the string is passed to `show_qr_window` as the variable `color`, so you can use `color_code = color`. You also have to change all of the `bg = 'color_code'` to `bg = color_code`, as `color_code` is a variable, not a string. 
The rest of your code seems to work (I haven't tested the qr code generation as I don't have that module installed). Here is the code with all of the fixes:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyqrcode
from tkinter import colorchooser  
  
def choose_color():
    # variable to store hexadecimal code of color
    color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title ="Choose color")
    if color_code != None:
        show_qr_window(color_code[1])
 
root = Tk()
button = Button(root, text = "Select color",
                   command = choose_color)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()

def show_qr_window(color):                    
    ws = Toplevel()
    color_code = color
    ws.config(bg = color_code)
    def generate_QR():
        if len(user_input.get())!=0 :
            global qr,img
            qr = pyqrcode.create(user_input.get())
            img = BitmapImage(data = qr.xbm(scale=8))
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning('warning', 'All Fields are Required!')
        try:
            display_code()
        except:
            pass

    def display_code():
        global img
        img_lbl.config(image = img)
        output.config(text="QR code of " + user_input.get())


    lbl = Label(
        ws,
        text="Enter message or URL",
        bg=color_code
        )
    lbl.pack()

    user_input = StringVar()
    entry = Entry(
        ws,
        textvariable = user_input
        )
    entry.pack(padx=10)


    button = Button(
        ws,
        text = "generate_QR",
        width=15,
        command = generate_QR
        )
    button.pack(pady=10)

    img_lbl = Label(
        ws,
        bg=color_code)
    img_lbl.pack()
    output = Label(
        ws,
        text="",
        bg=color_code
        )
    output.pack()
    
    ws.mainloop()
```

Assuming `generate_QR()` and `display_code()` work as they should (I haven't tested them but they look fine), this code will run as expected.